# Integral can't find how to do it: $\int\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have to find this integral $$\int\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}dx$$
This is how I began: $$\int\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}dx=2\int\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx$$
Then I tried substitution $e^u=x$ to get $u=\ln(x)\longrightarrow du=\frac1{dx}\rightarrow dx=\frac1{du}$

$$2\int\frac{\ln(x)}{x}dx=2\int\frac{\ln(e^u)}{e^u}\frac1{dx}$$
But then it gets complicated, and I'm not sure if the steps I've done are right. Need some help guys.

Comment: Correction: $du = \frac{1}{x}dx$ and use $ln(e^u) = u$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln x=u\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x}dx=du\Rightarrow\int\frac{2\ln(x)}{x}dx=2\int udu=u^2+c=\ln^2x+c$$

Comment: but why ln(x)=u => dx/x=du and not 1/dx=du?

Comment: @user157374 Because $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Ah right, get it now! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\ln x=y\implies \frac{dx}x=dy\implies\int\frac{\ln x}x\ dx=\int y\ dy$$

Answer (score 1):

It should be
$du = \frac1x dx $

Comment: Why?? Derivative ln(x) is 1/x

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Rewrite the integral as
$$
2\int\ln x\ d(\ln x).
$$

Comment: How please? I can't seem to recognize that

Comment: @user157374 $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln x)=\dfrac1x\quad\Rightarrow\quad d(\ln x)=\dfrac1x\ dx$.